# meaning of math symbol in probability expression?

Tags: statistics

anyone knows the meaning of the marked symbol in the pic and its Latex syntax?

[image: equation]

Comment: Some context would be helpful.

Comment: It is the function which is $1$ if $x_1=j$ and $0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an indicator function that is 1 if its argument is true and 0 if it is false. The latex syntax is $\mathbb{I}$ (\mathbb{I}).